# bash permission denied: Can't echo to the stdin of a running process?

Tags: bash, unix, process, pipe, echo

I'm trying to echo a command to the stdin of a running process, thus:

`echo -en '<Hex Command>' | /proc/<pid>/fd/0`

but I'm denied permission. I tried wrapping it within `sudo sh -c` but faced the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: As a follow up question, if I want to redirect the output of echoing to the stdin of the above process to a txt file (i.e. chain redirection), since I expect hex output from the process that my terminal cannot read, how could I do it? Directly adding another > doesn't work.

Comment: Whats the error message ?

Comment: Tangentially, perhaps a better RPC mechanism would be a FIFO or socket, depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The answer by @eduffy below, plus you may want `stdout` or `stderr` instead of `stdin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pipe `|` operator is for communication between two processes.  You want the redirection operator `>` because the operand on the right is a file.

**Edit**: BTW, the permission denied error is because the file `/proc/<pid>/fd/0` doesn't have executable permission.

Comment: As a follow up question, if I wanted to redirect the output of echoing to the `stdin` of the process to a txt file (i.e. chain redirection), since I expect hex output from the process that my terminal cannot read, how could I do it? Directly adding another `>` doesn't work.

Comment: You could use the `tee` command. That'll take its stdin and copy it to stdout plus the list of files given on the command line.  Since you want to go to two files, you could do something like this `echo ... | tee myfile.txt > /proc/pid/fd/0`

Comment: I actually need to write the stdout of the _process_ whose stdin I'm redirecting the echo to - I believe `tee` will simply write to both the stdin of the process and the files I list. It's the (hex) output of the process that I need to write to the file. Any thoughts on how I could do that?